# object is not a function in iron-router routes at onBeforeAction hook's this.next()

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm running iron-router 1.0.7, and my `onBeforeAction` hook is causing an exception. Here's the stack trace:

```
Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: object is not a function
    at Router.onBeforeAction.except (http://localhost:3000/lib/router.js?ebfe803416134e7c5b16265486b3998532289c58:45:8)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?a427868585af16bb88b7c9996b2449aebb8dbf51:1199:36
    at _.extend.withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:955:17)
    at Router.addHook.hookWithOptions (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?a427868585af16bb88b7c9996b2449aebb8dbf51:1198:27)
    at boundNext (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?0e0f6983a838a6516556b08e62894f89720e2c44:424:31)
    at Meteor.bindEnvironment (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:983:22)
    at Router.onBeforeAction.only (http://localhost:3000/lib/router.js?ebfe803416134e7c5b16265486b3998532289c58:28:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?a427868585af16bb88b7c9996b2449aebb8dbf51:1199:36
    at _.extend.withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:955:17)
    at Router.addHook.hookWithOptions (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?a427868585af16bb88b7c9996b2449aebb8dbf51:1198:27)
```

and here are the hooks that are referenced:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    //check if it's a logged in user
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
      //if they aren't redirect them to login
      this.render('login');
    } else {
      //if they are let them through
      this.next();
    }
  },
  //the routes we want this if logged in check for
  {only: ['profile', 'logout', 'users']
});

// Redirects users to the survey until they have answered all the questions
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('questions');
  var answered = getUserAnswers();
  var unanswered = Questions.find({ _id: { $nin: answered } }, {sort: {priority: 1}}).count();
  if (unanswered && Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'manage-users')) {
    this.next();
  } else if (unanswered) {
    this.redirect('survey');
  }
  this.next();
},
  {except: ['survey', 'passwordReset', 'logout', 'settings', 'login']});
```

It seems to be the last `this.next()` that's causing the exception (That's the line referenced in the first line of the trace.), but I can't tell why. If I put a breakpoint on it in DevTools, it runs twice just fine. Then, on the third stop, `next` is undefined. Any idea why this is happening? The routes still seem to work normally despite the exception.

Comment: I'm not sure why next becomes undefined, but consider subsciribing in a waitOn block, or checking if the subscription is ready before searching for answer/questions.

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock Thanks. How do I do a waitOn block on the hook? I thought I could only do that on a route.

Comment: You can define global onwait filters on the router object.

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock Ah, cool. Would that impact performance on routes that don't need that particular subscription? I guess it wouldn't really matter since I'm subscribing before each route anyway, right?

Comment: I'm not sure. There are definitely multiple ways to do these things. I personally try and avoid subscribing anywhere except onwait or templates themselves. Are you sure except doesn't work for global onwaits? To get around it without using ifs is to create new routecontrollers that inherit from routecontroller

Comment: Also performance isn't an issue here. It's just about which solution is cleaner and more maintainable.